# JQuery (only about CSS ) DataTable plugin's layout positioning

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

[image]

At the picture above there's a 'search' box on the upper-right, which part of the following codes that manage it ? :

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

I try it again and again , but i couldn't find it, i tried to inspect the elements but have no idea what' i'm doing. I really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the search box?

Comment: @zgood I just want to move it horizontally , like float:left or something like margin-right:80 so it doesn't get far on the right side , my table is ultra widht , but i don't know which part of css that manage this input, the thing (class="" or id="" )that refer to this input.

Comment: Look at the doc [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) to see how you can render out the search box differently. The search box is represented by the `f` character (for filtering).

Comment: can you post the html too? Or give us a link to the project?

Comment: But to answer your question the class `.dataTables_filter` is the element you would want to target in your CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change where the search box is rendered you can use the "dom" option to define a template of what and where things render. See [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) for an explanation (`f` is the character used for the search box).

If you want to target the search box in your CSS you can use the `.dataTables_filter` selector. This is the wrapping element for the search box and contains the actual search input.

Comment: Thank you so much @zgood , may God bless You for helping me, I know it's hard enough to find the answer, i wish i could upvote but , reputation limitation,, thanks again